# Count the times of a linux kernel thread when it's executed on the CPU

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads

If I don't modify the linux kernel and recomplie the kernel, can I get the times of a linux kernel thread once it's executed on the CPU over a period of time?

I can get the thread's PID, but how to count the times?
Does module programming can solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "called times" exactly?

Comment: @Mat when the thread is called in the function schedule(), it can be called one time.

Comment: Are you talking about [context switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) ?

Comment: @Mat: yeah, that's what I mean

Comment: Then search for that, e.g. "linux find number of thread context switches " in google. You'll end up on Stack Exchange pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

What about static variable.I think it will update itself.